Jackson: Is there a way to annotate all class members as required?
I have the following class as an API response
class User {
    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private String email;

    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private String username;
}

and I want to annotate all members as required.
I marked each property as required. It solves the problem, I just wish to know if there's an easier/less verbose way to do this.

I do not think that you can do this at the class level using Jackson. The closest you can do is by using @JsonCreator which can be used at the constructor level but still you will have to provide required = true for all the fields:
    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty(required = true) String email, 
                @JsonProperty(required = true) String name, 
                @JsonProperty(required = true) String username) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
    }

Personally, i like using @JsonProperty on each fields individually.

If you need it global (not only in User class), I would try:
spring:
  jackson:
    deserialization:
      fail-on-missing-creator-properties: true
      fail-on-null-creator-properties: true



This only works in Spring applications (the OP didn't specify if they were using Spring). Without Spring, you can configure like this: new ObjectMapper().setConfig(new DeserializationConfig(etc))

In addition to what was said by @k314159, I don't have easy access to the project configuration. That's why I wanted a class-level solution
